# Median of One Row Based on Number In Corresponding Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to calculate the median of one row, based on values in another row. For instance, let's suppose `Row A` has several different numbers and `Row B` has other unrelated numbers, but each column is a different month. I want to calculate the median for numbers in `Row B` only when the number in the same month in `Row A` is above `1000`.

What would be the Excel formula?

```
          Jan  Feb    Mar  April  May   June

Row A    500  1200    675  700    1800  2000
Row B    -100  400     6     18   -300  1200
```

Edit (from author's comment): Looking for one formula to first identify the numbers above $1000 in Row A and then the median of the numbers in row B that are in the same month as that first criteria?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data?

Comment: ROWS have numbers,  COLUMNS have letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay assuming you are mixing up the rows and columns, this will do what you want:

=MEDIAN(IF(B2:G2>1000,B3:G3,""))

but after typing it, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make sure it's an array function.

And remember to substitute the range however you need.

[image: One interpretation of the question]

Edit: To clarify how this works (use Evaluate Formula to see it in action): The array formula looks at Row A and notes which are greater than 1,000 (Feb, May, Jun) then takes the corresponding numbers in  Row B (Feb=400, May=-300, Jun=1200). The median of the three numbers (1200, 400, -300) is of course 400.

Old:
Personally, I would have a hidden row (H) with the formula in each Hi: =IF(Ai>1000,Bi,"") then take the median of that row.

Comment: There should be a formula to do this though

Comment: Right, but shouldn't and isn't there one formula to first identify the numbers above $1000 in Row A and then the median of the numbers in row B that are in the same month as that first criteria?

Comment: See my new answer.  =MEDIAN(IF(A2:A6>1000,B2:B6,"")) and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array function.  I've tested it, and it works correctly.

Comment: @ArinTaylor I appreciate that, but I'm looking for one formula

Comment: That is just one formula - ignore everything after "Old:"

Comment: Great to hear!  If everything is working, can you remove the down vote?

Comment: Yeah the range can be anything you want.  It just depends on how he has it set up (notice he says "Row A" so I still don't know if it's column-wise or row-wise)

Comment: Okay let's do it that way, I added a picture and showed it as rows.

Answer (score -1):

You would use something like the following (pseudo code, without seeing your spreadsheet):  Assuming that column "n" holds the month information

You might use something like `=if($An>1000,Median(B),"")`

Comment: That doesn't take into account the same month part